# Using @EntityGraph with JPA constructor expressions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a query that uses a constructor expression.  For the most part it works, but I wanted to reduce the number of queries on the database.  So I tried FETCH and @EntityGraph, but I am getting

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy ...

I tried removing the `FETCH` and just use `JOIN` to fix the problem, but it does not do the fetch operation.

Is this even allowed or possible with Hibernate/JPA?

Code wise it looks something like

```
@Query("select new example.BillingTargetAndStudent(bt,s) from Student s, BillingTarget bt where s.id = bt.targetID and bt.account.status = :accountStatus and bt.account.organization = :organization")
Stream<BillingTargetAndStudent> streamAllByOrganizationAndStatusForStudentList(Organization organization, AccountStatus accountStatus);
```

What I want to do is FETCH bt.account in the same query along with s.user.attributes.  The `bt.account` isn't too hard to workaround, but the s.user.attributes would not be possible with the constructor expression as it is a collection

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to use the Stream<Object[]> and `select bt, s from ...` then have a converter that changes Object[] to call the constructor expression

```
default Stream<BillingTargetAndStudent> streamAllByOrganizationAndStatusForStudentList(Organization organization, AccountStatus accountStatus) {

    return streamAllByOrganizationAndStatusForStudentList0(organization, accountStatus)
        .map(o -> new BillingTargetAndStudent((BillingTarget) o[0], (Student) o[1]));
}

@Query("select bt, s from Student s join fetch s.user u join fetch u.attributes, BillingTarget bt join fetch bt.account a where s.id = bt.targetID and bt.account.status = :accountStatus and bt.account.organization = :organization")
Stream<Object[]> streamAllByOrganizationAndStatusForStudentList0(Organization organization, AccountStatus accountStatus);
```

I can reduce the query slightly by putting in *one* `@EntityGraph`

```
@EntityGraph("Student.forStudentList")
@Query("select bt, s from Student s, BillingTarget bt left join fetch bt.billingContractTargets bct join fetch bt.account a where s.id = bt.targetID and bt.account.status = :accountStatus and bt.account.organization = :organization")
Stream<Object[]> streamAllByOrganizationAndStatusForStudentList0(Organization organization, AccountStatus accountStatus);
```

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Student.forStudentList",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("schedules"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "user", subgraph = "user.attributes"),
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "user.attributes",
            attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("attributes")})
    }
)
```

But I am limited to just one and it has to be the entity for the repository. I cannot say

```
@EntityGraph("BillingTarget.forStudentList")
@EntityGraph("Student.forStudentList")
```